# Piping long-running processes

Tags: python, linux, bash

I'm fairly new to Linux/Python programming. I tried googling about this but could not find anything useful.

I wrote a simple script that reads lines from a serial port and prints them (as they are read) to stdout. Here's the relevant code:

```
ser = serial.Serial(args.port)
while True:
    print(ser.readline())
```

I also wrote a script (this is only for testing purposes) that echoes lines read from stdin to stdout. Here's the code for that:

```
while True:
   print(args.prefix + input())
```

I'm using python3, and the scripts are named serial.py and echo.py respectively.

What I would like to do is to pipe the output of serial to the input of echo (echo will later be replaced by a script that writes to a database), and leave those running indefinitely.

I tried both scripts separately and they work fine, but nothing gets printed when I pipe both commands:

```
./serial.py --port /dev/ttyACM0 | ./echo.py
```

It does work when I pipe echo to itself:

```
awer@napalm:~$ ./echo.py --prefix AAA | ./echo.py --prefix BBB
hi!
BBBAAAhi!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help on this.

Best regards

Comment: The underlying assumption here is the proper \n terminated strings are coming through the serial port. Does such assumption hold? You can verify it by specifying a timeout to `readline`, as indicated [here](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html#readline)

Comment: Try using `./serial.py | od -c` to see the actual character codes that are being sent. Check whether the lines end with `\n` or `\r`.

Comment: Can you build a reproducer that someone else can use to see the problem *without* content coming in from a serial port? (If not, that indicates pretty clearly that it isn't a generic issue with "piping long-running processes", as your title implies).

Comment: BTW, bash isn't responsible for passing content between processes that are piped together -- it just sets up the FIFOs and lets the processes handle their own communication. From that perspective, I'm hard-pressed to consider the bash tag appropriate here: You'd have the exact same problem with the same FIFOs (connecting the two same programs) set up from C, Python, a non-bash shell, &c.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue related to a buffered stdout. Try to run the serial.py using the '-u' flag of the python3 interpreter, which will force stdout and stderr to be unbuffered as stated by the doc:

> ```
>    -u     Force  the  binary  I/O  layers  of  stdout  and  stderr  to  be
>           unbuffered.  stdin is always buffered.  The text I/O layer  will
>           still be line-buffered.
> ```